# JavaFX 2 and setCellValueFactory() in Scala?

Tags: java, scala, javafx-2, javafx

I am trying to follow this JavaFX 2 guide:

http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/table-view.htm#CJAGAAEE

I use Scala instead of Java and it looks like this for me:

```
<TableView fx:id="test">
     <columns>
         <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="Message" />
     </columns>
</TableView>
```

And code:

```
val c = test.getColumns.get(0) // Get the first column.
c.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory[Foo, _]("message")) // Foo is my model with a single SimpleStringProperty called "message".

val observableFoos = FXCollections.observableList(foos)
test.setItems(observableFoos)
```

The problem I have is that the `setCellValueFactory` line causes:

> error: class type required but
>   javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory[com.myapp.models.Foo,
>   _] found c.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactoryFoo, _)

I don't understand how I am supposed to use this method. If I replace `_` with `String`, then I get:

> error: type mismatch; found   :
>   javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory[com.myapp.models.Foo,String]
>   required:
>   javafx.util.Callback[javafx.scene.control.TableColumn.CellDataFeatures[com.myapp.models.Foo,?0],javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue[?0]]
>   where type ?0 c.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactoryFoo,
>   String)

I can confirm that everything works fine if I remove the `setCellValueFactory` line -- I just don't see any content in the table -- just blank rows as expected..

Comment: Could you also post the Foo class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TL;DR:** It is easy in java to silently bypass type safety with respect to type parameters. 
Scala won't let you do that, short of performing an explicit cast. 
In addition, using `Table.getColumns` to retrieve the column means that the we lose the type of cell.
Solutions: cast your `TableColumn` instance to the proper type, or instantiate the column by hand.

The first problem lies in the signature of `Table.getColumns`: it returns a `ObservableList[TableColumn[S,_]]` (see http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html#getColumns()).
So your `c` val is typed as `TableColumn[Foo,_]`.
This means that you lose the type of the cell content (denoted by the second type parameter).

The only solution here is to properly type the column (`c`) using a cast:

```
val c = test.getColumns.get(0).asInstanceOf[TableColumn[Foo, String]]
c.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory[Foo, String]("message"))
```

This is quite logical: you have a list of columns where each column can contain objects of a different type. We would face the same dilemma with a scala List containing objects of different types, all unknown a priori: only a cast (or a match on the type, which is a cast in disguise) will let you get back the a specific type at compile time.

Note also that in many JavaFx examples around the web, people don't retrieve the columns through `Table.getColumns`. Instead, they instantiate them by hand and then call `setCellValueFactory` on it right after.
Doing the same would solve your problem (without any need for a cast), as you will yourself specify the type parameters:

```
val c = new TableColumn[Foo, String] // See ma, no cast!
c.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory[Foo, String]("message"))
```

Now, you might look at some java examples and notice that they don't actually provide **any** type parameter when instantiating their `TableColumn`:

```
TableColumn c  = new TableColumn();    
c.setCellValueFactory( new PropertyValueFactory<Foo,String>("name"));
```

And indeed it does compile. How so? Well the sad truth is that the above code is not safer than doing a cast, as it relies on java's backward compatibility for pre-generics aware classes.
In other words, because `c` is typed as just `TableColumn`  and not `TableColumn<?, String>` by example, the java compiler treat it as a non generic class and not perform any type checking regarding the type parameters of `TableColumn`.
Contrast this to what happens if you explictly set the type of `c` to a generic type (but with an unknwon cell type):

```
TableColumn<Foo, ?> name  = new TableColumn("Name");
name.setCellValueFactory( new PropertyValueFactory<Room,String>("name"));
```

In this case the compiler  emits a type mismatch error:

```
error: method setCellValueFactory in class TableColumn<S,T> cannot be applied to given types;
...
```

This is just like in scala when `c` is typed as TableColumn[Foo, _]

Answer (score 1):

I suggest trying to use the long form of `PropertyValueFactory`:
(Sorry I am not familiar with Scala so wrote in Java)

```
 c.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Foo, String>,
             ObservableValue<String>>() {
     public ObservableValue<String> call(TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Foo, String> f) {
         // f.getValue() returns the Foo instance for a particular TableView row
         return f.getValue().messageProperty();
         // or
         return new SimpleStringProperty(p.getValue().getMessage());
         // if you omit messageProperty() in Foo model class.
         // However omitting it, causes the property listener could not be attached resulting 
         // unable to refresh (synchronize) tableview row item value when the backing 
         // Foo's message value is changed.
     }
  });
```

Note that your Foo model must be something similar to:

```
public class Foo {
    private SimpleStringProperty message;

    public SimpleStringProperty messageProperty() {
        return message;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message.get();
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message.set(message);
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not solve the problem: if there is a type mismatch with `PropertyValueFactory[Foo, String]`, there will be a type mismatch with `Callback[TableColumn.CellDataFeatures[Foo, String],
             ObservableValue[String]]`

Comment: @RégisJean-Gilles. Hmm.. I'm not claiming this will solve the problem. It is suggestion to try it out.